# Can't import UIComponent in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So I add this line to my .FLA file in the first frame's script:

```
import mx.core.UIComponent;
```

I receive this error:

```
1093: Syntax error.
```

in UIComponent.as line 54. Double click on that in the Compiler Errors panel and I see:

```
#include "../core/ComponentVersion.as"
```

OK, the syntax error is likely in ComponentVersion.as ... except it really, really shoud not be. And if I load that file into the Flash editor and syntax check it has no errors. However, if I copy the sole non-comment line of that file (static var version:String = "2.0.2.127"; ) into UIComponent in place of the #include, it works????

Now I get this error:

```
5007: An ActionScript file must have at least one externally visible definition.
```

Excuse me? This is a class definition file suppled with Flash!

Any clues would be gratefully received.

I'm using Flash CS4 (10.0.2).

Comment: Odd since `#include` went out with ActionScript 2

Comment: As you might guess, I'm much more familiar with AS 2 than 3. But ... why does CS4 come with an obsolete version of UIComponent? I'm going to try a reinstall with total wipeout between, and see if that resolves it.

Comment: I would be sure your publish settings is set to AS3. Sounds trivial, but I'm the first to tell I'd overlook it easily.

Comment: Why are you using **mx.core**.UIComponent?  Are you importing the Flex SDK?  Flash Pro has it's own version of UIComponent: fl.core.UIComponent.

Comment: The mx libraries are not supplied with flash. So what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @JohnGiotta, thanks, I had checked and rechecked and it's definitely AS3.

Comment: @merv, please make your comment an answer so that I can mark it as correct. That's it. To answer your and The_asMan's questions: because I was copying code from examples I found without having a deep knowledge of the classes involved. Thank you both.

Comment: @Carl - Glad you were able to clear that up.  The flash libraries have certainly gotten confusing over the last few years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are intentionally trying to import the Flex SDK, you should be using the UIComponent class from the library included in Flash Pro, [fl.core.UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html), and not the Flex counterpart, **mx.core**.UIComponent.